# How to configure a regex search string to match either a string or a string plus an additional string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am configuring the following regex search string in Python:

```
^([Mm](an|anchester)).*([Uu]nited|[Uu])$
```

I want it to match any combination of **Man/Manchester** (upper or lower-case m) and **U/United** (upper or lower-case u.)

Is there a more concise way to configure my regex strings?

I feel like using, for example, **an|anchester** is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can add an optional group for (M)`anchester` and (U)`nited`. Here is an example:

- [`man(?:chester)? u(?:nited)?`](https://regex101.com/r/H0cQVG/1)

[image]

Keep in mind that setting a regular expression as case insensitive (which is what you want) is usually a setting you pass to the regex function/compiler. For example, with python it would be: [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE). Here's a quick sample in python of how you could do this:

```
import re
strings = ['man United', 'man u', 'Xman u']
for string in strings:
    string, re.match(r'man(?:chester)? u(?:nited)?', string, re.IGNORECASE) or 'No match'

('man United', <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f01d53763d8>)
('man u', <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f01d5376370>)
('Xman u', 'No match')
```

I am using `re.match` which 'anchors' the regex so I don't have to do `^...$`, but you can also use `re.search` which will search the whole string, in which case you may want to use anchors.

---

Finally, from a comment you have below on another answer, if you want the space to be optional -- for example, you want to match `manU` or `manUnited` then make the space optional, that is, add a `?` after the space, so it would be `^man(?:chester)?\s?(?:united)?$` (now using the anchored version, in case you find that version more helpful).

Finally, one more option if you only want to allow the `M` and `U` to be capitalized is to use a character class as you've done in your question, `^[Mm]an(?:chester)? ?[uU](?:nited)?$`.

[image]

Hope this helps!